# ConnectionFactory doesn't recognize application.properties properties

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-data, singleton

I have a ConnectionFactory class in order to use in my Jdbc Appender to save logs in a mysql database, but, I want to use properties in ConnectionFactory class to avoid leaving sensitive data exposed in the code, but, it is a singleton class, so its never get the values of my properties, the properties are always null. Can someone help me, is there any way to bring the application.properties properties into the ConnectionFactory?

I have this ConnectionFactory class:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverManagerConnectionFactory;
import org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnection;
import org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory;
import org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource;
import org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;

public class ConnectionFactory {
    private static interface Singleton {
        final ConnectionFactory INSTANCE = new ConnectionFactory();
    }

    private final DataSource dataSource;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.user}")
    private String user;
    @Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
    private String password;
    @Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
    private String url;

    private ConnectionFactory() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("user", user);
        properties.setProperty("password", password); // or get properties from some configuration file

        GenericObjectPool<PoolableConnection> pool = new GenericObjectPool<PoolableConnection>();
        DriverManagerConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new DriverManagerConnectionFactory(
                url, properties
        );
        new PoolableConnectionFactory(
                connectionFactory, pool, null, "SELECT 1", 3, false, false, Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
        );

        this.dataSource = new PoolingDataSource(pool);
    }
    public static Connection getDatabaseConnection() throws SQLException {
        return Singleton.INSTANCE.dataSource.getConnection();
    }
```

And, my application.properties:

```
spring.cloud.compatibility-verifier.enabled=false

# database configs
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDatabase
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle=true
spring.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

Is there any way to bring the properties into the ConnectionFactory class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a response, you can add the environment variables in a singleton class using this code:

```
System.getenv("MY_ENV_VARIABLE");
```

This way, you get the environment variables.

If you really need to get the properties of applications.properties, you need to create a **Properties properties** variable, and then you can use this code:

```
try (InputStream input = YourSingletonClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("application.properties")) {
        properties.load(input);
} catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

To get the value of any propertie, use  **properties.getProperty(key);** where the 'key' is the name of your propertie.